# Ubuntu Sofware Center problem

Tags: software-center, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix 'Check your Internet connection' error in software center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77487/how-to-fix-check-your-internet-connection-error-in-software-center)

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 . I have a problem with the Software Center. I am not able to install anything from it. After I entered my authorisation password it gives the following error:

> Failed to download package files check your internet connection.

After that it says

> Requires installation of untrusted packages. The action would require
>   the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.

Comment: what software are you trying to install? I had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure your internet connection is working. Can you browse websites in your browser when this error occurs?

You might need to update the package metadata. Close Software Center. Open the Unity Dash (top icon in the dock) and type "Update Manager". Open the Update Manager, and click on "Check". Wait for it to finish (this needs an internet connection), close it, open Software Center, and try to install. Note that installing the updates suggested by Update Manager is not necessary for this (but is recommended in general).

Alternatively, instead of the Update Manager you could also do `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal.

Comment: I have my internet connection,and I'm able to browse all files and getting my downloads too.but only for software center its not getting connected.for update manager also connection is available and able to install all updates.Now no more updates are remaining to install.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Update Manager, click the *Settings...* button, and check *Source Code* under the Ubuntu Software tab. Then, back in the main Update Manager window click *Install Updates*. ([source](http://jaypeeonline.net/tips-tricks/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages-error/))

If it doesn't work then can you post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and then `gpg --list-keys` from the terminal?

Comment: Its not showing any errors.for update manager also connection is available and able to install all updates.Now no more updates are remaining to install.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type "Update Manager" in Dash Home (search)
2. Open the "Update Manager" and click "Settings" [You can find at the bottom]
3. Check-in "Source" and close the Menu.
4. Now try to "install" any software.
5. Make sure your Internet connection is Working.